# How to set no current Tab in TabLayout - Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

when I create a `TabLayout` with a `Viewpager`, my first tab will be selected by default, when I start the app.

What I want is, that when I start the app, that NO tab will be selected, only if I click one, it should be selected.

Is there a way, how to realize it?

**EDIT:** 
I have 2 tablayouts and 2 viewpager for a screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".ManagementActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/slidingTabs"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/slidingTabs_2"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_management);

        //create tablayout for the first row
        ViewPager viewPager_1 = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        ManagementPagerAdapter adapter_1 = new ManagementPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), true);
        viewPager_1.setAdapter(adapter_1);

        TabLayout tabLayout_1 = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.slidingTabs);
        tabLayout_1.setupWithViewPager(viewPager_1);


        //create tablayout for the second row
        ViewPager viewPager_2 = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager_2);
        ManagementPagerAdapter adapter_2 = new ManagementPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), false);
        viewPager_2.setAdapter(adapter_2);

        TabLayout tabLayout_2 = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.slidingTabs_2);
        tabLayout_2.setupWithViewPager(viewPager_2);
```

I want 2 rows for tabs, but when I start, only that one column will be chosen of them, now 2 columns will be chosen and I don't want it.

Comment: A `ViewPager` always shows a page. So, what page will be shown when the app starts? And, if that page does not have a tab, if the user swipes to that page, what happens?

Comment: Showing empty screen when your app starts is not a good way to please your users. They might think something is wrong with the app.

Comment: The idea is, that I want to create 2 rows of such tabs, 
if I do so, I have 2 rows with tabs and in both rows, the first column will be selected. 

My wish would be, that I only can choose one between them..